# Angular - How to add debounceTime on a mouseLeave event?

Tags: angular, typescript, mouseevent

The purpose is that when the mouse leaves the div, it triggers the 'mouseleave' and emits a value with an EventEmitter.

But the part that i really can't get working is when the 'mouseleave' event is triggered again in less then 2000 miliseconds after it was already triggered, it shouldn't do anything.

Just want to avoid that when the user moves a lot with the mouse it emits the value too many times.

I got this code at the moment, but doesn't work as it should be.

```
  @Output() public mouseLeave: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();

  public event$: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  @HostListener('mouseleave') public onMouseLeave(event: MouseEvent): void {
    this.event$.next(event);
    this.event$
      .pipe(debounceTime(2000), takeUntil(this.mouseLeave))
      .subscribe(() => {
        console.log('Mouse left');
        this.mouseLeave.emit();
      });
  }
```

Comment: move `this.event$
      .pipe(debounceTime(20...` piece to ngOnInit

Answer (score 0):

As the `onMouseLeave` is called many times, you are newly subscribing every time to the `this.event$`. Therefore the mouseLeave event is triggered much to often and fast.

As Andrei in the comment sayed, you should move this part

```
      .pipe(debounceTime(2000), takeUntil(this.mouseLeave))
      .subscribe(() => {
        console.log('Mouse left');
        this.mouseLeave.emit();
      });
```

into the ngOnInit Method, to only subscribe once.

Furthermore don`t forget to unsubscribe properly to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks @Slin F for your answer. But then triggers it the mouseLeave Emitter only once.
The purpose is to emit it, and then have a delay for 2000 miliseconds (so it can not be emitted again during that time). And after the 2000 miliseconds it can be emitted again.

Comment: do you still call `this.event$.next(event);` inside the `onMouseLeave` Function?

And i think you use the `takeUntil` wrong in this example. Try it without the takeUntil.
With this usage you end the subscription after the first emit, so it does not emit again. But i think you want to capture all emits until the component is destroyed.
To Clean up correctly you could create a Subject `destroyed$` and then use `takeUntil(this.destroyed$)`. But you need to implement ngOnDestroy and call there `this.destroyed$.next(); this.destroyed$.complete();`

Answer (score 0):

Use `fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'mouseLeave').pipe().subscribe()` in `ngOnInit()`